# How do you get the Custom Game Novice achievement in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

The Achievement is Exploration > Custom Game Novice.

It reads

```
Win 3 solo evenly matched Custom Games against any A.I. opponents.
```

I have gone Single Player > Versus A.I > Play versus A.I. and beat the the Medium A.I. at least 3 times and I have beat the hard A.I. once. The Achievement still shows 0/3 completed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the **multiplayer** menu, choose "Custom Games", Create Game, and in the game lobby, "Add AI".

"Evenly matched" in this case means you and the opponent AI have the same handicap percentage specified.

Comment: I got annoyed by this one, kept trying to do the Single Player option. The achievement is confusing.

Comment: I tried this, I tried again setting the Game mode from Melee to Custom and still no achievement, do I have to change the difficulty level?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Go to Multiplayer
2. Click "Create Custom"
3. Choose the map
4. Use the settings box on the right to change the category to "Custom"
5. Have your opponent at 100% hp
6. Click "Start Game"